# How to Bind username in shell unified Sapui5

Tags: sapui5

i want to bind username from odata service into username in shell fragement  view 
there is my code

```
<core:FragmentDefinition

class="viewPadding">
<u:Shell
  icon="./images/sap-logo.png"
        id="myShell">
        <u:headItems>            
            <u:ShellHeadItem
                tooltip="Home"
                icon="sap-icon://home"
                visible="false"
                press="handlePressHome" />
        </u:headItems>

        <u:user>
            <u:ShellHeadUserItem
                image="sap-icon://person-placeholder"
                username="{UserCo}"
                press="handleUserItemPressed" />
        </u:user>

    </u:Shell> 

    </core:FragmentDefinition>
```

and there is odata service

```
<EntityType Name="USERCO" sap:content-version="1">
   <Key>
     <PropertyRef Name="UserCo"/>
  </Key>
  <Property Name="UserCo" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="30"        sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false"/>
  </EntityType>
```

any idea please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: Set the model on the component or the fragment's parent view using setModel().

Step 2:Next, in the code where you have instantiated the fragment, use the addDependent() method to add the fragment as a dependent to the parent view (the one where the model is set.

```
<Parent View Reference>.addDependent(<fragment instance>);
```

Step 3: Then ensure that binding is correct in the fragment.

Step 4: Test

Step 5 (Debugging): If still not working, launch your application and check whether the binding is correct (you may have missed a slash etc.) For this you can use the SAPUI5 diagnostics. Press Alt-Ctrl-Shift-S. In the pop-up select Control Tree and navigate to your bound element "u:ShellHeadUserItem". Select it and check the "Binding Infos" tab.